# How to download Mountain Lion installer after changing a store?

Tags: macos, install

I'm going to upgrade my machine with ssd drive, so I want to make a clean install. I was told that I can redownload the installer via Mac App Store, but the problem is that I used the store of other country for buying ML and now I'm using a different one (my country was introduced to it's own app store just recently, so I changed the store), so there is no Mountain Lion in Purchases section.

I've payed for it once, I don't want to pay for it for the second time. I know I can get it from torrents but whether there is really no 'legal' way?

p.s. I know about internet recovery posibility but the speed is an issue so it would be much better to get an installer in advance before the actual installation and stuff. So the question is 'how?' :)

**upd** as through the comments, i should be able to log into previous store but it's not.

1. i press flag in bottom right corner, then select my previous store, then
2. i choose 'purchases' section, it writes 'you should log in to see your purchases'
3. i log in, the app tranfers me back to my store

I know I can switch the store in my Apple ID settings but it is quite a bit painful — i should rebing the credit card, i'm cleaning my purchases list which is obviously not very cool.

Comment: you can still log in in to your previous apple store

Comment: @Buscar웃 thanks for your answer. i've updated the question — it would be awesome if you could have a look. basically, i can't just log in into my previous store

Comment: I do not think you can get a free of charge software from official sites. But you could contact your local Apple Store and see if they can transfer you account holdings.